# Comet streaming: XHR streaming and Forever iFrame still possible in 2015?

Tags: iframe, xmlhttprequest, streaming, comet

I know I should probably use WebSockets or Server-Side Events, but what happened to the Comet Streaming techniques that involved writing chunked data from a server to either an `iFrame` or as a response to a `xmlHttpRequest`? I have stumbled upon multiple demos but none of them work as intended any more and since most of the material on this type of streaming is quite old, I'm wondering whether or not it is still doable in the year of 2015?

Just to be clear, I'm referring to the Comet techniques where the server keeps a connection open using chunked transfer encoding flushing new data on the fly. Incremental rendering in browsers should presumably make this data available, either as it comes in in the case of an `iFrame` (e.g. "Forever iFrame") or by reading the `responseText` property of the `xmlHttpRequest` object when its `readyState` returns `3` (e.g. "XHR streaming"). However, all browsers seem to buffer the data until the connection is closed, no matter how much bogus preamble I add before starting to send real data. Also, I'm not referring to the special case with `Content-Type` set to `multipart/x-mixed-replace` which works in Firefox only, but an approach which seems to have worked on most of the browsers a few years back.

*Does anyone know if current browser behaviour has obsoleted these Comet streaming techniques?*

Example demos:

**Polling `responseText` on load through `xmlHttpRequest` object:**

http://ajaxify.com/run/streaming/xmlHttpRequest/countdown/
http://ajaxify.com/run/streaming/xmlHttpRequest/

**Slow loading of regular page, incremental rendering does NOT kick in for me:**

http://ajaxify.com/run/streaming/

**Polling `iFrame` content on slow `iFrame` load:**

http://ajaxify.com/run/streaming/xmlHttpRequest/iframe/

These demos does not use chunked transfer encoding but resulting behaviour is the same, that is, incremental rendering isn't happening.

**Article on Comet streaming:**

http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/

---

---

**Short version conclusion:**

All the Comet techniques still work, however, in my case the antivirus got in the way of things in an unforeseen manner so make sure to test things on different computers and in safe mode as well to be sure if it doesn't work!